# Using machine learning in R

Tags: r

Using machine learning in R
while generating formula `~. ,data,`

what does `.` indicate

for example

```
fit <- svm(factor(outcome)~., data= train, probability= T)
pre <- predict(fit, test, decision.value= T, probability= T)
```

Comment: The . means "all other variables". Please take a look at the help page on `formula`

Answer (score 2):

The dot means "everything else". I.e. say you're dataset has the variables x , y and z then  `y~.` would get translated to `y ~ x + z`

Answer (score 1):

The help page (`?formula`) can shed some light regarding `.` interpretation :

> There are two special interpretations of . in a formula. The usual one
>   is in the context of a data argument of model fitting functions and
>   means ‘all columns not otherwise in the formula’: see terms.formula.
>   In the context of update.formula, only, it means ‘what was previously
>   in this part of the formula’.

However, note that `.` is used differently by `reshape` and `reshape2` packages:

`?cast`

> There are a couple of special variables: "..." represents all other
>   variables not used in the formula and "." represents no variable

Answer (score 0):

It means "all other variables", that are present in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Here (.) indicates everything else . Let for Strong datasets there has four variables named age, height, weight and strength. Here strength is the response variable. Now we want to create a linear model where strength is the response variable and other three factors are dependent. Now if we can write the model such as,

```r
model = lm(strength ~ height + weight + age , data = Strong)
```

This model can be write shortly,

```r
model = lm(strength ~., data = Strong)
```